# Expertland / Stackexchange - are the sites the same?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

this site seems to have a copy of my stackoverflow question and the stackoverflow site. Is this legal?

http://expertland.net/questions/sl54u5y8yu34x5v7y9192u9o3m62lqm54/listby-1.html

Comment: Thanks rene. Reported.

Comment: Anyone want to mark as duplicate and close?